# Column width synchronized across multiple jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have three jquery datatables on a page, the first three columns of each have the same type of data, a series of model names. I'd like to synchronized the width of the first three columns in each datatable to the width of the same columns in the other two datatables.

Ideally the width of the first column in upcomingTable should be the same as the width of the first column in runningTable and historyTable but never wider then is needed by at least one of the tables to fit its contents.

The table data is being loaded and updated periodically via ajax calls and so can change at anytime.

Table 1:

```
        <table id="upcomingTable" class="tabForm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Program</th>
                    <th>Campaign</th>
                    <th>Portfolio</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>Run Type</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Table 2:

```
        <table id="runningTable" class="tabForm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Program</th>
                    <th>Campaign</th>
                    <th>Portfolio</th>
                    <th>Organization</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>Elapsed</th>
                    <th>Stage</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Table 3:

```
        <table id="historyTable" class="tabForm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Program</th>
                    <th>Campaign</th>
                    <th>Portfolio</th>
                    <th>Organization</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>Run Time</th>
                    <th>Results</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!